# How to create angular 2/4 component in runtime (javascript5 with DSL)

Tags: javascript, angular

Component located on another server and it must work after async load without addign in module declaration or entryComponents

component example:

```html
app.LoginComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'login',
    template: '<h1>Hello component</h1>',
  }).Class({
    constructor: function () {
    }
  });
```

Comment: Http://Blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/     This is a good read

Comment: do yourself a favor and work with typescript ;)

Comment: I know how work with typescript) do you now how do it in typescript?